# Does this sentence sound naturally?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence  written by my friend, does this sentence sound naturally?  the sentence is :'if you use your selling skill at your working as a saleman, its your ability,but if you use it to make up rumors,to set up others,to hide the  evil ,to rewrite the truth, it is your sin, and dont  you believe the punishment will come at u one day?     I think some phrase usage is not proper here, but I where, would u please check it?

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentence does not flow, 'if you use your selling skill as a **salesman** sounds better than the at your working part.